# Zabbix mmcblk0: Disk read/write request responses are too high

Tags: sd-card, readwrite

I installed Zabbix on my Raspberry Pi 4 4GB.
So, I was building my dash and noticed a different alarm.

```
Zabbix server   mmcblk0p2: Disk read/write request responses are too high (read > 20 ms for 15m or write > 20 ms for 15m)   
Zabbix server   mmcblk0: Disk read/write request responses are too high (read > 20 ms for 15m or write > 20 ms for 15m)
```

I`m using a SanDisk High Endurance SD, but I suppose the alarm it is related to the SD card lower access speeds, despite being a good one (I guess).

Does anyone knows how to optimize the read/write on RPi?
Thanks